# Pure JS Add class in many divs of the same id

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to add class " hidden" in many divs of the same id.

```
function show_wzorce(x) {
    document.getElementById("" + x + "").className += " hidden";

    var divs = document.getElementById("" + x + "");
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        divs[i].className += " hidden";
    }
}
```

Comment: ID **Should** be unique. Use `classList` to add class. `divs[i].classList.add('hidden');`

Comment: classList isn't supported in IE9 if you need to care about that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ID has to be unique. You can do the same thing but with getElementsByClassName (there is a "s" after element)

Your code should look something like this:

```
function show_wzorce(x) { // assuming x is string
    var divs = document.getElementsByClassName(x); //this returns an HTML Collection. But works as an array 
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        divs[i].className += " hidden";
    }
}
```

Comment: If `x` is string, you don't need `"" + x + ""` quotes around it.

Comment: @Tushar thanks. Just paying attention to his question :)

Comment: @TreeNguyen `document.getElementsByClassName(x)` returns a HTMLCollection which is an array like object (have `.length`, `[0]`, `[1]`, ...) that are dynamic meaning if the DOM changes the HTMLCollection will update accordently

Comment: @dev-null what do you mean?

Comment: You write `var divs = document.getElementsByClassName(x); //this returns an array`

Comment: Oh yes. I understand it's an object but citing it as an array might be easier to understand :)